# dompdf failed to load document in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, dompdf

Here is my code in book_pdf.ctp

```
<?php
    require_once(ROOT . DS . 'Vendor' . DS . 'dompdf/dompdf' . DS . 'autoload.inc.php'); 
    use Dompdf\Dompdf;

    // instantiate and use the dompdf class
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();

    $dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

    // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

    // Render the HTML as PDF
    $dompdf->render();

    // Output the generated PDF to Browser
    $dompdf->stream();

    ?>
```

Whenever I download the document it says failed to load it.

Is this concerned with cakephp

Comment: Would be better if you used this plugin https://github.com/friendsofcake/cakepdf

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is perfect to generate pdf on cakephp

https://github.com/DaoAndCo/cakephp-dompdf